# Proof of Rejection Sampling

Tags: rejection-sampling, accept-reject

I'm trying to go through the proof of rejection sampling and I found a paper [ACCEPTANCE-REJECTION SAMPLING MADE EASY](http://web.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~mcasquilho/CD_Casquilho/MC_Flury_ar.pdf) which provides several helpful explanations. For Lemma 2, the paper claims that if $Z$ has a uniform distribution $A$, and let $B \subset A$ and then the conditional distribution of $Z$ given $Z \in B$ is uniform in $B$. However, it does not provide proof. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: the paper is behind a paywall. It will be helpful for you to write the lemma in the post so that the post is fully self-contained.

Comment: @LucasRoberts I just changed the source so it should work now.

Comment: Still, links break, and having to click through / click back-and-forth doesn't make it easy on your readers either.

Comment: As a thought experiment, imagine $x \sim \text{U}(0,1)$, and you find out that $x < 0.5$.  What do you suppose the conditional distribution of $x : x\in(0, 0.5)$ is ?

Comment: @jbowman Correct me if I'm wrong. Is that just $x$ ~ U(0,0.5)?

Comment: You're right.  The point is, of course, that the Uniform distribution is constant, therefore each subset of it is also constant, which in turn implies that each subset of it is a Uniform distribution too, writing loosely.

Comment: @jbowman Thank you so much! However, is it possible that you could provide a little more formal explanation? I was trying to use the definition of conditional probability to derive the conditional probability in your question but it failed. The way I do is: $P(x\in (0,1)|x\in (0,0.5))=\frac{P(x\in (0,1),x\in (0,0.5))}{P(x\in (0,0.5)}=\frac{P(x\in (0,0.5)}{P(x\in (0,0.5)}=1$, which is wrong.

Comment: Well that's why I'm putting this in comments!  I may add a real answer tonight my time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll construct a proof of a simpler proposition which should make it clear how the more general one is done.  Let $z \sim \text{U}(0,1)$.  Then the density $p(z) = 1$ and the cumulative distribution $P(z) = z$.  Now let us find the conditional distribution of $z | z < c$, i.e., $z \in (0,c)$.

Using the definition of conditional probability, $p(z|z<c)p(z<c) = p(z)$.  In our case, $p(z<c) = c$ from the definition of the cumulative distribution and $p(z) = 1$ from the definition of the density.  Rearranging terms gives:

$$p(z|z<c) = {p(z) \over p(z<c)} = {1 \over c}$$

Since $p(z|z<c)$ is constant for all $z$, the distribution is clearly Uniform over $(0,c)$. (The "constant for all $z$" part is why the distribution is called  "Uniform", so this is really definitional.)

Comment: Thanks! This is clear and helpful. I tried to think of it but it only works under the discrete case.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. Isn't $p(z|z<c)p(z<c) = p(z,z<c)$? Why is $p(z,z<c)=p(z)$? To me, $p(z,z<c)$ should be equal to $p(z<c)$ since $z$ could be larger than $c$.Thanks!

Comment: You can see that can't be the case because the multiplication won't work out.  In order for your calculation to work, $p(z|z<c)$ would always have to equal 1, regardless of the probability distributions involved.  The trick is that the range of $z$ changes, and I should have made that explicit with indicator functions.

Comment: Thanks for the probabilistic explanation that the integral of the probability should be 1. I am still trying to make an explanation based on the term of the intersection to explain that why $P(z,z<c)=P(z)$. So far my thought is that if $z\sim U(0,1)$ and the probability I randomly draw a $z$ and this $z$ is less than $c$ should just be $p(z)$, this is due to that I just draw one $z$ so which area this $z$ is should not affect the probability I draw it. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Think of $p(z<c)$ as a normalizing constant.  If we restrict $z < c$, it's clear that $p(z|z<c) = a*p(z)$, where $a$ is some constant independent of $z$, because we aren't changing the shape of $p(z)$ over the range $z<c$.  We are now left with the following problem: $\int_{z<c}p(z)\text{d}z \neq 1$, so it's not a real probability distribution.  How to make it one?  If we set $a = 1/\int_{z<c}p(z)\text{d}z$, then clearly it WILL integrate to 1.  And... $p(z<c) = \int_{z<c}p(z)\text{d}z$.  So dividing $p(z)$ by $p(z<c)$ just normalizes it over the range $z<c$ so it will integrate to 1.